# Trim door slab width by 1/4". Worth dealing on my own or order to the size?

Tags: doors

Store can order them with custom size (adds +2 weeks and ~$60/slab). They are solid core, paint grade (primed).

Comment: you could use a hand plane to shave off 1/4" ... practice on a 2x4 before doing the door

Comment: So... I'm reading between the lines and assuming that you're putting a new door in an existing opening. If that's the case, there are some subtleties about hanging a door (recommend you research Gary Katz, among others), and you might want to have that extra quarter of an inch to work with. (And I sincerely don't mean to be insulting when I mention this -- I'm a working carpenter and I've done it -- but doors have two widths.)

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate What does “doors have two widths” mean? (Doors come in many widths...)

Comment: If you don't mind me giving my take on the 2 widths, one edge on the side of the door that will have the knob is typically beveled, usually 2-3 degrees making one side of the door a different width than to other side of the same door. Also in the past I have seen door leaves that are sized for a given opening for example 2-6 or 3-0 and the door sized up to 1/4" smaller for that size opening. Actually it is supposed to be 3/16" smaller for two 3/32" gaps on either side/edge, and with the beveled edge, even smaller on the opposite side/face. Then I seen openings sized for a full 2-6 or 3-0 door.

Comment: Do you have a circular saw and clamps available?

Comment: Thanks, @Jack for saying it better than I could.

Comment: as mentioned in comments, yes, I'm replacing existing slabs and don't want to touch jambs etc. Over weekend I picked a stock door from local homedepot to see what actual difference is and while dealing with new door slab, decided to order them pre-sized to fit and not to cut them by myself. Good news is that 3 of my openings were wide enough to fit standard sizes, which helped to cut total of the order.

Answer (score 1):

WAIT! Don’t cut anything! Your rough opening may be an inch or more wider than your current opening! First pull your inside trim and see if there are any shims or spacers, this is normal. So make sure the size of the rough opening prior to doing anything as your new door may fit just fine. Doors and windows are rough framed and are installed after the framework and roof are installed. So your new door will probably fit without modification.

Comment: there are 2 shims in couple of openings, unfortunately, whoever installed it before, put shims on glue (it's visible) and it is impossible to remove them without damage to the jamb.

Comment: Ok trying to reuse the jambs you will need to cut the door and set the hinges and strike plate/ door latch hole. I usually order pre hung as matching an old jamb can take a lot of time and more chances for mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Cut 1/4" off with a rail saw and sand & finish. Easy if you have tools & skills, if not pay for it.

Comment: Hi, Mike. "This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content.". FYI...